# Appending two default value to a dropdownlistfor MVC 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

How do I append two default value to a dropdownlistfor

```
 List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        sStreet = "<option value=0>Select</option>";
        sStreet = "<option value=1>Other</option>";
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tname.Rows)
        {
            txt = @dr["StreetName"].ToString();
            valu = @dr["id"].ToString();
            sStreet += "<option value=" + valu + ">" + txt + "</option>";
        }
        return Content(sStreet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Other", Value = "1" });
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tname.Rows)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dr["StreetName"].ToString(), Value = dr["id"].ToString() });
}
//then pass items to the view through your model
```

on your view you should then set up the dropdownlistfor like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.items)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. It worked! I also tried '<option value=0>Select</option><option value=0>Other</option>'

Comment: very glad it helped.  would you mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding another option after the select option

```
 items = "<option value=0>Select</option><option value=0>Other</option>";          
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            txt = @dr["StreetName"].ToString();
            valu = @dr["id"].ToString();
            items += "<option value=" + valu + ">" + txt + "</option>";
        }
```